# How to deploy & publish cordova ios from VS2015

Tags: android, ios, macos, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have develop an Cordova App in vs2015 and I'm able to deploy on android, test and publish on Play Store.

So, I attach my remote iMac and compile&build ios platform but I don't find a simple and robust path for deploy.

First of all, to deploy on App Store I need to do it only from iMac... is possible to deploy directly from Win10 after build from mac?

So if it's correct I need to open the .xproject and prepare to send to app store but the .xproject change  on every new deploy from VS (the remote_build create a new folder on every build).

Comment: You can submit your app to app store by following "Step 5: Create the package" of [this link](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/#package-the-ios-version-of-your-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good resource for you to see how to "**Package your Cordova app so that you can publish it to a store**".

You can learn how to prepare them for Android, iOS and Windows App Store publish.

Here it is at this url: [Package your Cordova app so that you can publish it to a store](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tutorial-package-publish-readme/)